# Input arguments to a JavaScript inline function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, inline

I'm reading [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) example snippet in googlemaps API.

---

The below is an extract from the snippet.

`getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom)` is a separately defined function.

The value of the `getTileUrl` attribute is assigned to the output of the inline function which takes `(coord, zoom)` as arguements.

```
var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({

     getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
            ....
            ....
     },
     ....
     ....
});
```

---

**Question:** What are the values of the `coord, zoom` variables when they are called inside the inline function?

I don't see them assigned to anything prior to calling them.

Answer (score 1):

It's taking the parameters from getTileUrl which belongs to the ImageMapTypeOptions object specification.

```
getTileUrl  
Type:  function(Point, number): string
Returns a string (URL) for given tile coordinate (x, y) and zoom level.
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ImageMapTypeOptions